# Query to Concatenate Address

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I need to figure out how to concatenate mailing addresses in the following format:

```
address1 address 2 (sometimes not present) city state zip5 - zip4 (sometimes not present
```

I have tried to do this from an example I found online:

```
Stuff(  
    Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address1, '') + 
    Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address2, '') + 
    Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_City, '') + 
    Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_State, '') + 
    Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_ZipFive, '') +
    Coalesce('-' + Buyer_ZipFour, ''), 1, 1, '') AS [MailingAddress]
```

To these addresses:

```
Address 1               Address 2   City    State   Zip
210 Independence Blvd               Tucson  AZ  85641
1 Palace Lane           Suite A     Toad Kingdom    FL  37058
123 Star Lane                       Star Kingdom    OH  54678
```

But the results are:

```
210 Independence Jr Blvd Tucson AZ 85641-
1 Palace LaneSuite A Toad Kingdom FL 37058-
123 Star Lane Star Kingdom OH 54678-
```

Any help in resolving these would be great.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with what you have. Or maybe you are trying to get multiple columns? Would help if you posted some details of the table and the desired results.

Comment: Addres: 1 Palace LaneSuite A Toad Kingdom FL 37058-  needs a space in between address 1 and 2, the hyphen should be only display when there are the additional 4 digits to the zip code.

Comment: This would be a simple answer if we aren't guessing as to what you have for tables and data. Also what you want as output. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your empty data is blank - not null, therefore coalesce won't do the job. Instead try:

```
stuff(  
    coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address1, '') + 
    --coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address2, '') + 
    case when coalesce(Buyer_Address2,'') <> '' then ' ' + Buyer_Address2 else '' end +
    coalesce(' ' + Buyer_City, '') + 
    coalesce(' ' + Buyer_State, '') + 
    coalesce(' ' + Buyer_ZipFive, '') +
    --coalesce('-' + Buyer_ZipFour, '')
    case when coalesce(Buyer_ZipFour,'') <> '' then '-' + Buyer_ZipFour else '' end
    , 1, 1, '') as [MailingAddress]
```

Comment: Why `COALESCE()` on the first column `Buyer_Address1`? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: True - that wasn't part of your question - but yes its not required.

Comment: Also in the `CASE` there's no need to use `COALESCE` either. Just `CASE WHEN Buyer_Address2 IS NOT NULL ...`

Comment: If you are 100% sure that it will never be null then yes - personally I often handle the null case even if I don't expect it.

Comment: I don't think you need "stuff" either - but I was only trying to solve the specific issue mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the CONCAT function...

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(mt.Address1 + ' ', mt.Address2 + ' ', mt.City + ' ', mt.State + ' ', mt.ZipFive, '-' + mt.ZipFour)
FROM 
    dbo.MyTable mt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Buyer_ZipFour` would appear to have empty strings rather than `NULL`.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
Stuff(Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address1, '') + 
      Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_Address2, '') + 
      Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_City, '') + 
      Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_State, '') + 
      Coalesce(' ' + Buyer_ZipFive, '') +
      Coalesce('-' + nullif(Buyer_ZipFour, ''), ''), 1, 1, ''
     ) AS [MailingAddress]
```

Based on your sample results, the rest of the fields don't appear to have this issue.